# Protecting CSST Through Studs - Are there no off-the-shelf solutions?

Tags: plumbing, natural-gas, csst

I am having a hard time meeting the protection requirements outlined in the manufacturer's specifications. I'm installing [HomeFlex](http://www.homeflex.com/) CSST in California - California's plumbing code defers to the manufacturer for most of the installation requirements for CSST.

HomeFlex requires that horizontal runs through studs have 5" of protection on either side of each stud through which it passes (when it is within 2" of the edge, inevitable when dealing with 2x4s). However, HomeFlex does not provide a branded product to accomplish this (which is generally preferred, as mixing/matching brands in the same CSST install is usually a show-stopper for inspections), and I am unable to find anything of sufficient dimensions @ 16 gauge hardened steel that meet the requirements for protecting CSST.

At this point, the only 2 options I can see to meet the requirements established by HomeFlex, are to either fabricate my own striker plates or to find the odd-sized 1-1/4" steel pipe that is noted as an acceptable alternative, and cut it to 11-1/2" lengths (5" + 1-1/2" + 5"). Are these really my only options (other than ripping it out and using black pipe)? What are others doing to address this requirement?

Here's the relevant part of the documentation (full doc is [here](http://homeflex.com/downloads/HOME-FLEX_Installation_Manual.pdf)):

[image: Relevant manufacturer requirements]

**Update:** I have found some products on the horizon from other CSST manufacturers (namely Gastite), however these, made by any brand, do not appear to be yet available for sale from anywhere:

[image: New Gastite Striker Plates]

Comment: Can you post a link to the documentation, or quote the exact text here?

Comment: Apologies, I've added a screenshot of the relevant part of the documentation. I'll go ahead and add a link to the full document as well.

Comment: Seems very strange that they would have the 5" on both sides requirement and only list a part in their instructions that is 9" long...  If you talk to an installer in your area, let us know what they do, just out of curiosity.

Comment: Curious if there is any update on what solution you eventually went with?

Answer (score 4):

The [manufacturer's installation manual](http://static1.1.sqspcdn.com/static/f/1060336/23796373/1417502678550/HOME-FLEX_Installation_Manual.pdf?token=aJ7Ln04Q9Yh%2BEDhetOHJJ0X5RXA%3D) describes the plate that can be used, and even includes the part number.

> [image]

Which is available at [Home Depot](http://www.homedepot.com/p/HOME-FLEX-4-in-x-9-in-CSST-Striker-Plate-11-3070SP/205700074), and [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00IKVNEOU).

It also says in the Protection section of the document "*For tubing routed horizontally between studs, striker plates should be installed at each stud, and Flexible Protective Conduit, or other approved conduit, should be installed across the entire length of the run.*" (see point 4 below), and "*schedule 40 steel pipe has been found acceptable by CSA International for puncture protection.*". So you could always use schedule 40 steel pipe to protect the pipe. Just cut the pipe in 12" sections, and install the tubing in the pipe where it passes through studs.

> [image]

Comment: These plates appear to be intended for other scenarios, as they don't meet the stated requirements of protection over the stud, and for 5" on either side (they would have to be at least 11-1/2" long on one side to be long enough).

Comment: @Wilco In that case. I would contact the manufacturer, and ask them if they have larger plates, or how to properly install the plates they do have.

Comment: @Wilco If you read points 4 and 5 of the Protection section, you'll see that you're allowed to use schedule 40 steel pipe to protect the tubing.

Comment: The sch-40 steel pipe is the option I'm currently leaning towards, though the size they specify (1-1/4") isn't as common. I just want to be sure I'm both interpreting their specifications correctly, and that there aren't any more straightforward options. It sounds like there may not be though.

Comment: Cutting up the black steel pipe sounds like potentially the simplest and most robust option. You might consider notching the studs and putting in one long run of that pipe, if the wall isn't load bearing. Alternately getting some flat steel from a local supplier and even just running one long strip might be just as easy.

Answer (score 0):

These type of protection plates are sold at most electric supply stores, and probably with plumbing supplies as well ( I see them exclusively in the electric department at Lowes or Home Depot).  Here is a link to a product page for a [protection plate](http://www.lowes.com/pd_14385-166-PL4_0__?productId=3374518).  Here's what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately in this case, these striker plates don't meet the manufacturer's requirements of protecting the CSST both over the stud and for 5" on either side.

Comment: Is using multiple plates not an option?  I'm sorry I didn't read carefully - I just knew these plates were 5" and sounded perfect.

Comment: @Wilco What about [this](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Unbranded-HOME-FLEX-4-in-x-9-in-CSST-Striker-Plate-11-3070SP/203080789)?  They may come in various sizes...  I'll update my answer if this is what you need.

Comment: No problem. Those are closer, but still don't match what the manufacturer is requiring. The plates essentially need to extend out from the stud on either side b 5". It seems silly because they do offer plates (the ones you linked in fact), but they aren't the right size. Not sure what they wan't people to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use a flat steel plate designed for framing applications (Simpson Strong Tie makes plenty). They are abundant in lengths to satisfy minimum (11 1/2") for 2 x 4s.

[image]

Cutting up schedule 40 iron pipe feels to me like you are defeating the purpose of using CSST.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative product to the other answers / references is a Simpson Strong-Tie [PSPN516Z](https://www.strongtie.com/protectandrepair_miscellaneousconnectors/ns-pspnz_productgroup_wcc/p/ns.pspnz) "Galvanized 5 in. x 16-5/16 in. 16-Gauge Protecting Shield Plate Nail Stopper".

[image: example installed]